# django-admin/.py, command not found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, frameworks, django-admin

I tried both admin-django, and admin-django.py, but it just tells me that it can't find the command. I use Arch Linux and installed python-django with pacman. I also tried to set $PATH to /usr/local/bin, how someone on SO suggested, but it didn't help. Would anyone here know what I could have done wrong?
(python -c "import django" works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Python packages via your OS package manager is really hit or miss. It's likely that their setup script wasn't configured correctly (or, is an old version that doesn't match the documented behavior). You should [follow the installation instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/) and use `pip` instead -- it should be safe to download `pip` from your package manager, and then use it for all of your Python packages after that.

Also, their [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/) mentions that the command is **django-admin.py**, not **admin-django.py**, but, since your title is correct, I assume that was a typo.

Comment: This worked, just one more question is django by default for python3?

Comment: @TsumugiKotobuki Thanks, please upvote/accept this answer if you found it helpful. Nothing is "by default" for any version of Python -- it depends on what version of `pip` you install it with (or what version your package manager picks for you).

Answer (score 0):

in effet you should use the command django-admin in this way

```
django-admin startproject _the_name_of_your_project
```

if tell you " command not found "

Maybe you should consider to reinstall django :

```
sudo pip uninstall
```

Best Practice : Use venv

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Go in your working directory :

```
source env/bin/ activate
```

Now you are in a virtual enviroment :

```
sudo pip install django
```

Try the command django-admin